# Model objects filtering doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I try to filter objects for foreign key field in my admin class for Circuit model class with:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "current_firmware":
            kwargs["queryset"] = FirmwareVersion.objects.filter(firmware__circuit_model=self.model)
        return super(CircuitAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I can't figure out why but the list of choices for field `current_firmware` is empty after the filtering. Maybe anyone could help me with this.
I've got these classes:

```
class FirmwareVersion(models.Model):
    firmware = models.ForeignKey(Firmware)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Firmware(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    circuit_model = models.ForeignKey(Versiiplates)

class Versiiplates (Model):
     version = ForeignKey(Plates)
     nomer_oboznachenie = CharField(max_length=8)

class Circuit(models.Model):
    circuit_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Versiiplates)
    current_firmware = models.ForeignKey(FirmwareVersion, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you wanted to use `self.model` in your filter expression: in a ModelAdmin object, that just refers to the model class, not the instance.

In fact this probably isn't the way to do this sort of filtering at all. Rather than defining `formfield_for_foreignkey`, you probably need to define a custom modelform, and set the queryset there using `self.instance` as the comparison.